# JPA: merging entities based on a 'natural key'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Possibly I'm understanding the concept wrong, but here is my problem:

I want to store two types of data in my database:

1. game positions (uniquely represented by some lengthy string, containing two lists of moves - one for moves possible in this position and one for moves leading to this position)
2. game moves (represented by a smaller string, linking two positions)

In classes:

```
@Entity
public class Move {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String representation;
    private Position positionBeforeMove;
    private Position positionAfterMove;

    ...
}

@Entity 
public class Position {
    @Id
    private String representation;
    private List<Move> movesLeadingToPosition;
    private List<Move> movesLeadingFromPosition;

    ...
}
```

I want to store a set of games. In this context, the positions are unique, and the moves may occur multiple times in the database.

My naieve implementation uses two tables:

```
MOVE
number   id                    (PK)
varchar2 representation
varchar2 positionBeforeMove    (FK)
varchar2 positionAfterMove     (FK)
...

POSITION
varchar2 representation        (PK)
...
```

This works fine; using `EntityManager.merge(position)` I can grow my `POSITION` table as I store more and more games, while keeping the positions unique.

However, the solution is not optimal: I'd much prefer to have a generated `id` like I have in the MOVE table!

```
@Entity
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String representation;
    private List<Move> movesLeadingToPosition;
    private List<Move> movesLeadingFromPosition;

    ...
}

MOVE
number   id                    (PK)
varchar2 representation
number   positionBeforeMove_id (FK)
number   positionAfterMove_id  (FK)
...

POSITION
number id;                     (PK)
varchar2 representation        (Unique)
...
```

But when I implement this, I end up with duplicate representations, because the `EntityManager.merge(...)` merges based on the *specified* Id, not the *natural* key.

Is there any way I can let java (JPA / Hibernate / ...) merge the positions based on the natural key, while still allowing me to use an ID as the key to the table? Or, would I need to merge the positions manually? (for example: Whenever I want to store a move, would I need to retrieve the `positionAfterMove` and `positionBeforeMove` from the database, add the move to `movesLeadingToPosition` and `movesLeadingFromPosition` respectively, and then update the positions in the database?)

(context: I'm using Java 1.7, JPA, and a MySQL database)

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible; `merge()` is done using entity key (the `@Id` target).

Probably you need to add a `@NaturalId` or mimic as described  in [JPA equivalent to Hibernate's @NaturalId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254083/jpa-equivalent-to-hibernates-naturalid) and check for duplication insertion using business method

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `@NaturalId`! Can you confirm that I will have to _'merge positions manually'_? (that seems to be the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058875/hibernate-natural-id-duplicate-issue). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think so,but - if you have time - wait for someone else answer; maybe people with different experiences can give us another point of view